# Hghlighted field with red border in Wordpress Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress

I want to get this effect http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/ by Wordpress Contact Form 7.

I set in css

```
.wpcf7-not-valid{
    border:1px solid #d73333!important;
}
```

But when I insert value into the field the red border do not disappear.

Comment: If you inspect the element, does it still have the `.wpcf7-not-valid` class on it, after you have entered a value? If so, you have a Javascript problem. You are using Chrome Developer tools or something similar, right? Are there any Javascript errors in the console? Happy debugging, and good luck!

Comment: When I inspect the element it still have .wpcf7-not-valid class. There are no any errors in the console.

Comment: It looks like there is a logic error in the script that handles validation. In the debugger, try setting a breakpoint on the statement that is supposed to remove the class, see if that line of code even executes. If not, then step through the code one line at a time, and you will hopefully see the problem. If you can replicate the problem with a minimal example, that should make the problem more obvious. If you get that far and still can't find the source of the problem, you should post the example in a [jsfiddle](jsfiddle.net) so that the rest of us can take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Got a good solution. In wp-content\plugins\contact-form-7\includes\js\scripts.js

Changed

```
$.fn.wpcf7NotValidTip = function(message) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var into = $(this);
            into.append('<span class="wpcf7-not-valid-tip">' + message + '</span>');
            $('span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip').mouseover(function() {
                $(this).fadeOut('fast');
            });
            into.find(':input').mouseover(function() {
                into.find('.wpcf7-not-valid-tip').not(':hidden').fadeOut('fast');
            });
            into.find(':input').focus(function() {
                into.find('.wpcf7-not-valid-tip').not(':hidden').fadeOut('fast');
            });
        });
    };
```

to this code

```
$.fn.wpcf7NotValidTip = function(message) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var into = $(this);

            $theParent = into.parent("span");
            $parentInp = $theParent.parent("input");

            into.find(':input').css('border-color', '#d73333');

            into.find(':input').mouseover(function() {
                into.find(':input').css('border-color','#cccccc');
            });
            into.find(':input').focus(function() {
                into.find(':input').css('border-color','#cccccc');
            });
        });
    };
```

Comment: keep in mind that this solution will be overridden every time you update the plugin. So you will have to remember to change this after every plugin update.

Comment: Downvoted because you are modifying plugin core file. You should NEVER do this. So please don't call it "good solution"

Answer (score 0):

```
.wpcf7-validation-errors, .wpcf7-mail-sent-ng {
padding: 5px;
color: #E68B8B;
background-color: #FDF5F8 !important;
border: 1px solid #FDE2E2 !important;
width: 518px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal solution because it all depends on how you styled your form

Anyway you can try use something like that:

```
span .wpcf7-not-valid {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000 !important;
}
```

*Note: using `!important` is never the best way to do anything with css*